# How can I set the name of my program in the Open With dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, exe, .net-assembly, open-with

I want the program to read `VLC (Move on end)`:

[image: a]

I've modified my Assembly Info to the following, to no avail:

[image: a]

How can I alter the name displayed in the Open With dialog?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with visual studio. Why retag it with them again?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set it in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Hans' answer, this is what did it for me:

**export.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\VLCMoveOnEnd.exe]
"FriendlyAppName"="VLC (Move on end)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\VLCMoveOnEnd.exe\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\VLCMoveOnEnd.exe\shell\open]
"FriendlyAppName"="VLC (Move on end)"
```

Answer (score 4):

It is stored in the registry as the FriendlyAppName value under HKCR\Applications\YourExeName.

Described in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).