# wrong application name in Windows 8 "open this type of file" dialog

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-installer

I'm trying to set name of the application that appears when opening one of the file extension registered by my application's installer, right now it shows this:

---

Since I *can* post images...

In this dialog:
[image]
<sub>(source: [eightforums.com](https://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/22767d1370590392-new-app-installed-notification-disable-windows-8-new_apps-2.jpg))</sub>

It shows the full application path "C:/Program Files/.../myapp.exe" instead of the Application name

---

I'd like to have the application name appear there instead of the full command line path...

Here's the registry file which represents what I'm doing in the installer:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TalanSoft.GaeaLevel.v1]
@="Gaea Level"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TalanSoft.GaeaLevel.v1\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3/Gaea/bin/nt-x86/niw_ra.exe\",0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TalanSoft.GaeaLevel.v1\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TalanSoft.GaeaLevel.v1\shell\open]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TalanSoft.GaeaLevel.v1\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3/Gaea/bin/nt-x86/niw_ra.exe\" -I\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3/niSDK/data/\" -I\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3/niSDK/scripts/\" -I\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3/ham/scripts/\" -I\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3/Gaea/scripts/\" -I\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3/Gaea/scripts/gaea/\" -e -Dgaea.start_app_level=\"%1\" gaea/gaea.niw"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TalanSoft\Gaea\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="Gaea is a web development application developed by TalanSoft Co."
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TalanSoft\\Gaea3\\Gaea\\bin\\nt-x86\\niw_ra.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="Gaea"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TalanSoft\Gaea\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".level"="TalanSoft.GaeaLevel.v1"
".gaea"="TalanSoft.GaeaApp.v1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"Gaea"="SOFTWARE\\TalanSoft\\Gaea\\Capabilities"
```

I've setting up that way following the recommendation in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#intro

Any idea of how this has to be setup, I couldn't find any Win8 specific info.

Comment: I really can't (am not allowed to) post images because I dont have 10 reputations... I meant to post a picture of the actual problem - a screencap of the app, the picture is a link I found that looked similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a string value for your exe with `FriendlyAppName` under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications`, like:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\niw_ra.exe]
"FriendlyAppName" = "Gaea"
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#applications) describes all the options you can give for your application.

**EDIT**: found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14906900/1850797) saying the same thing afterwards